# Comparing two tables in sql query using join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have 2 tables.

table 1 = deliverable (which is a constant table)
table 2 = passed_deliverable

table 1 contains (primary key)deliverable_id, deliverable_title, deliverable_desc, admin_id, flag
table 2 contains (primary key)passed_deliverable_id, deliverable_id, user_id, flag

Now i want to echo out `deliverable_id` from `table 1` and my `WHERE` clause would be, it would not echo out `deliverable_id` from `table 1` which is already in `table 2`.

To be specific, I would like to compare `deliverable_id` in `table 1` and `deliverable_id` in `table 2`, if the `deliverable_id` already exists in `table 2`, it would not echo out in `table 1` when i use a query.

Here is what I have at the moment.

```sql
SELECT deliverable.deliverable_id, passed_deliverable.passed_deliverable_id, 
       deliverable.deliverable_title, deliverable.deliverable_desc,
       deliverable.adviser_id
FROM deliverable
INNER JOIN passed_deliverable
ON deliverable.deliverable_id=passed_deliverable.deliverable_id
WHERE deliverable.deliverable_id!=passed_deliverable.deliverable_id
```

Comment: so in summary, you want all the rows in `deliverable` which do not have en entry in `passed_deliverable`?

Comment: @Rhumborl absolutely right sir. thanks for getting my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` to check if no matching data exists in the other table. Query below returns all deliverables that have not passed.

```
SELECT 
  deliverable_id, deliverable_title, deliverable_desc, adviser_id
FROM deliverable d
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 'x' 
      FROM passed_deliverable pd 
      WHERE pd.deliverable_id = d.deliverable_id)
```

Comment: sir may i know what SELECT 'x' means?

Comment: Of course. It's just a constant value. It could as well be `1` or `'foobar'` or `pd.deliverable_id`. `[not] exists` merely checks whether there is a record returned from the subselect, and it doesn't care about the actual value that is returned. I use constant value 'x' for those cases, but that's just a convention I bumped into.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a left join to exclude rows in passed_deliverable:

```
SELECT deliverable.deliverable_id,
       deliverable.deliverable_title,
       deliverable.deliverable_desc,
       deliverable.adviser_id
FROM deliverable
LEFT OUTER JOIN passed_deliverable
    ON deliverable.deliverable_id = passed_deliverable.deliverable_id
WHERE passed_deliverable.deliverable_id IS NULL
```

This gets everything from `deliverable` then tries to join it to `passed_deliverable` if it exists. So you might get something in memory looking like this:

```
deliverable_id  passeddeliverable.deliverable_id  ... other columnss
1               1
2               NULL
3               3
```

Then your WHERE clause excludes the rows where `passeddeliverable` doesn't have a match (in my example id 2), i.e. `passed_deliverable.deliverable_id IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT deliverable_id
FROM deliverable
WHERE deliverable_id NOT IN (
  SELECT deliverable_id 
  FROM passed_deliverable
)
```